# Install Saxon jar in Eclipse for Java?

Tags: java, jar, saxon

I've downloaded the `Saxon` jar from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsaxon653jar.htm) site , and I'm trying to activate this `jar` file in `Eclipse` , however it doesn't work . I've put it in the `plugins` library and reopen `Eclipse`  .
This still doesn't help much .

I have a lot of imports like :

```
package net.sf.saxon.sxpath;
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.event.Builder;
import net.sf.saxon.event.Stripper;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.ExpressionTool;
import net.sf.saxon.instruct.SlotManager;
import net.sf.saxon.om.AllElementStripper;
import net.sf.saxon.om.NamePool;
import net.sf.saxon.om.NamespaceResolver;
import net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.IndependentContext;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.type.Type;
```

and from what I've looked over the web , those imports demand the `saxon.jar`  . Kindly explain how can I attach this jar .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the jar you need inside your project (e.g. with drag-and-drop), so it shows up inside Eclipse.

Then right click it and add it to the build-path.

You can now use it inside your project.

Answer (score 1):

The site you link to is for Saxon 6.5.3, which is very old; it's the XSLT 1.0 version of Saxon, and it uses completely different package names from the current version of Saxon, which is 9.4.

Your application seems to be using some very low-level interfaces in Saxon, so it's likely that it was written to work with a specific version of Saxon - it would be a good idea to find out which.